# Configure IIS To Send “text/html” In Response for IE11

Tags: asp.net, http, iis, internet-explorer-11

The updated version of Internet Explorer in Windows 8.1, IE11, has the following User Agent string as per [this](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2013/03/27/internet-explorer-11s-user-agent-string-what-does-it-mean/):

> Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko

Our website is correctly setting the Content-Type in the response to "text/html" for all browsers except for when we use the IE11 UA. For browsers sending the IE11 UA, it's incorrectly sending "application/xhtml+xml" instead. All browsers send "text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*" in the Accept header in the request.

Is there an IIS or ASP.NET web.config setting to allow "text/html" to be set for IE11 or a default? I'm not currently using any .browser files.

Comment: _"For browsers sending the IE11 UA, it's incorrectly sending "application/xhtml+xml" instead."_ - or is there something with accept- request headers?

Comment: @CodeCaster Yes, all tested browsers send "text/html, application/xhtml+xml, \*/\*" in the Accept header in the request.

Comment: are you open code based solution or it has to be IIS/Web.config solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fix was to update our .browser file that defaults to "text/html, application/xhtml+xml", which it ended up doing for IE11.